# capitalize first letter of each word in sentence using boost library

Tags: c++, string, boost

I was looking for a way to capitalize first letter of each word in a sentence using boost.
To make the code consistent i.e the final output will not have any space or tab if present in the input sentence. To get individual words I m using boost::alogrithm::split and for combining them back boost::algorithm::join . but how do I get each first letter capitalized ?

I tried this code

```
 #include <iostream>                                                              
 #include <vector>                                                                
 #include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>                                      
 #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

 int main()                                                                      
 {                                                                               
     using namespace std;                                                        

     string str("cONtainS            SoMe    CApiTaL WORDS");                    

     vector<string> strVec;                                                      
     using boost::is_any_of;                                                     
     using boost::algorithm::token_compress_on;                                  

     boost::algorithm::split(strVec, str, is_any_of("\t "), token_compress_on);  

     vector<string>::iterator i ;                                                

     for(i = strVec.begin() ; i != strVec.end(); i++)                            
     {
         (*i)[0] = boost::to_upper((*i)[0]);
         cout<<*i<<endl;                                                             
     }                                                                           

     return 0;                                                                   
 }
```

Comment: Are we talking ASCII or is it supposed to be Unicode compatible ? (hint: Boost does not support Unicode as far as I know)

Comment: as of now I m only considering ASCII . But yeah in future Unicode support will be required.

Comment: For Unicode you will need a unicode aware library, probably one like ICU, to actually capitalize the word; therefore the strategy of splitting + joining is costly at the moment but will work in the long run.

Comment: thanks , I thought **boost::to_upper((i)[0]);** will make the first letter capital but its making entire word capital. And yeah I will certainly check ICU :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code got me working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string str("contAins Some       CapItal WORDS");
    string result;

    vector<string> strVec;

    using boost::is_any_of;
    using boost::algorithm::token_compress_on;

    boost::algorithm::split(strVec, str, is_any_of("\t "), token_compress_on);

    vector<string>::iterator i; 

    for(i = strVec.begin(); i !=strVec.end(); ++i)
    {                                                                                

        boost::to_lower(*i);
        (*i)[0]=toupper((*i)[0]);

        cout<<(*i)<<endl;
        result += *i +" ";
    }  

    boost::trim_right(result);
    cout<<result;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The problem I figured out is that boost::to_upper() needs address not a value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to define how you determine what a sentence is.  The
simplest solution is that it is any sequence which ends with the regular
expression `"[.!?][\"\']*"` (since you've already eliminated white
space); this is actually simple enough that you could do it without
regular expressions.  Then memorize that you've seen it, and capitalize
the next word:

```
bool atEndOfSentence = true;
for ( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator current = words.begin();
        current != words.end();
        ++ current ) {
    if ( atEndOfSentence ) {
        (*current)[0] == toupper( (*current)[0] );
    }
    std::cout << *current << std::endl;
    atEndOfSentence = isSentenceEnd( 
            *std::find_if( current->rbegin(), current->rend(),
                           IsNotQuoteChar() ).base() );
}
```

with:

```
struct IsNotQuoteChar
{
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return ch != '\'' and ch != '\"';
    }
};
```

and:

```
bool
isSentenceEnd( char ch )
{
    return ch == '.' || ch == '!' || ch == '?';
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying :) . Your code looks a little complex :P . I did some hit and trail and got it to work. If you find any mistakes do tell me .

Comment: after reading your code . I used 'toupper' in my code
`        boost::to_lower(*i);
        (*i)[0]=toupper((*i)[0]); `
now its producing the right output . since I have less than 100 points I cant paste the solution here before 8 hours :P

Comment: @VickeyVerma Anything dealing with natural language (written or spoken) will be complicated:-).  Just defining what you mean by "capital letter" is non-trivial in an international environment---what you probably want here is what Unicode calls title case, and not upper case.  (And FWIW: there's a bug in the code I posted.  The argument to `toupper` must be cast to `unsigned char`, or undefined behavior may result.)

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that this doesn't use Boost and won't work with Unicode but provides a basic solution using standard library functions. I'm breaking on `isalpha` to dertermine the delimitation of words. Perhaps not the best way, but it's just an alternative:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str("  cONtainS            SoMe    CApiTaL WORDS");

    bool niw(true);
    string strC;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if ( niw && isalpha( str[i] ) )
        {
            strC += toupper( str[i] );
            niw = false;
        }
        else if ( ! niw )
        {
            if  ( isalpha( str[i] ) )
                strC += tolower( str[i] );
            else
            {
                niw = true;
                strC += str[i];
            }
        }
        else
            strC += str[i];
    }

    cout << str << endl;
    cout << strC << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my C++11 solution in case anyone is interested:

```
std::string s("some lowercase string");
s[0] = toupper(s[0]);
std::transform(s.begin()+1, s.end(),s.begin(),s.begin()+1, 
[](const char& a, const char& b) -> char
{
    if(b==' ' || b=='\t')
    {
        return toupper(a);
    }
    return a;
});
```